# how to uncompress a binary file which is application/gzip and enconding binary - linux

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, ibm-midrange

I've got some files which are supposed to be compressed and binary. I am trying to uncompress them, but I am not able to find the way to do it

What I can see is that the file is compressed and binary, but I have no idea how can I uncompressed to get the file with extension .bin ( those files are coming from an IBM AS/400 system )

```
$ file RPLMREP.20200831045319063541
RPLMREP.20200831045319063541: gzip compressed data, has comment, comment, last modified: Tue Sep  1 04:53:19 2020
$ file --mime-encoding  RPLMREP.20200831045319063541
RPLMREP.20200831045319063541: binary
$ file --mime-type RPLMREP.20200831045319063541
RPLMREP.20200831045319063541: application/x-gzip
$ gzip -d RPLMREP.20200831045319063541
gzip: RPLMREP.20200831045319063541: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "unknown suffix" error from gzip is a clue that it doesn't want to decompress the file because it doesn't have a `.gz` suffix. Either rename it...

```
mv RPLMREP.20200831045319063541 RPLMREP.20200831045319063541.bin.gz
gunzip RPLMREP.20200831045319063541.bin.gz
```

...or use redirection:

```
gzip -d < RPLMREP.20200831045319063541 > RPLMREP.20200831045319063541.bin
```

(or use the `-S` option to tell it to recognise your existing suffix, but since that's a datestamp, that doesn't feel right)

Comment: I got this error : `gzip: RPLMREP.20200831045319063541.bin.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated`

Comment: What you have isn't valid gzip data then, or it's been corrupted (byte ordering, ASCII-vs-EBCDIC, line endings, dunno) in some way. Just 'cos `file` recognises the magic bytes in the header doesn't mean the rest of the file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

When decompressing, `gzip` creates a file with a new name, which is the old name, but the suffix removed. For instance, you can decompress an file `x.z` by

```
gzip -d -S .z x.z
```

The suffix is specified using the `-S` option, but can not be empty.

You can do

```
gzip -d -S .20200831045319063541  RPLMREP.20200831045319063541
```

which decompresses into RPLMREP, or you can decrompress to stout and choose an explicit file name for the decompressed file:

```
gzip -dc RPLMREP.20200831045319063541 > RPLMREP
```